# Add new page in WooCommerce My Account page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So, I'm building a website and I need to add a new page in the WooCommerce My Account section. When you visit the My Account page you get options like Edit Profile, Orders, Downloads, Billing Details etc.. I want another Menu/Page there called "Sites", so the idea is that, I am a web designer, whenever someone buys a website from me. I want to add a field to their account, that shows them how many sites they own from my company.

So, when a person clicks on site it should show details in a table form. Like: Domain Name | Expiry Date |  Renewal Date | Login to Website (button)

I should be able to add a site and link it to the user from the wp-admin panel. It's basically like creating an order and assigning it to a user, and displaying it in the order section. But here, I want to replace it with "sites".

So, is there any existing plugins that I can tweak and combine to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this customly before, but you don't sound like you want a programmatic answer, please let me know if that's not the case, otherwise...

A quick search and I came up with [Woocommerce Account Pages](https://iconicwp.com/products/woocommerce-account-pages/).  I haven't used it, and it does cost $49, but it might be the most concise solution for you.  And it has a 14 day free trial.

Best of luck!